# Spurious signals around LO feedthrough in HP 8591A spectrum analyzer?

Tags: spectrum-analyzer

I am troubleshooting my HP 8591A spectrum analyzer. It is fully functioning, except for these spurious signals around the 0 Hz feedthrough. This noise is only within 15 MHz of DC.

Where should I look for the possible fault? I have checked every single signal path, test point, and everything is within the specs specified in the service manual.

[image]

Comment: AM radio? at 0.7 and 1.5MHz offset.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the first LO, in particular the YIG voltages on a scope. Any excessive noise on those supply/tuning lines could translate to side bands around the LO.

Similar checks for the 2nd LO will also be useful.

edit: the REF unlock error looks suspicious, and would point to some unwanted modulation of the LO.